# Launch terminal from code in Python

Tags: python, console, terminal, wxpython

I need to launch a python terminal from the code of one wxpython application when pressing a button. Is it possible?

Comment: Do you want to launch something like IDLE?

Comment: Yes, that would be good enough. Any ideas of how it could be done? (I'll search the web nonetheless and be back if I find an answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In wxPython land, you could load a window that has PyShell in it, which is a Python shell written in wxPython. The wxPython demo has an example. There's also PyCrust (also in the demo) which adds a few more features to PyShell.

Otherwise you could do it by using the subprocess module to open a console with Python in it.